# How to add key to dictionary by checking the value

Tags: python, dictionary

- I need to check 'Type' whether it '-' or ','
- create a new key with 'value' which is same as 'Type'
- if '-' then its 'or'
- if ',' then its '='

The sample dictionary is below

```py
{
    'RULES': {
        'rule1': {
            'Range': '0',
            'Type': '0-10'
        }
    },
    'rule2': {
        'Range': '1-10',
        'Type': '0,10',
    },
    'rule3': {
        'Range': '11-50',
        'order': '3'
    }
}
```

Expected out

```py
{
   'RULES': {
       'rule1': {
           'Range': '0',
           'Type': '0-10',
           'value':'0-10',
           'operator' :'or'
       }
   },
   'rule2': {
       'Range': '1-10',
       'Type': '0,10',
       'value':'0,10',
       'operator':'='
   },
   'rule3': {
       'Range': '11-50',
       'order': '3'
   }
}
```

Code

```
for i,j in a.items():
    for k,l in j.items():
        l['value'] = l['Type']
        if '-' in l['Type']:
            l['operator'] = '='
        if ',' in l['Type']:
            l['operator'] = 'in'
```

Got error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: well there are several ways to achieve this. What is your trouble here? Do you encounter any problems? As this is posted, it is rather a task than a valid question

Comment: @HansT Got error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: `Rules 1` has a nested dict.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA i have put l['value'] = l['Type'] which is in nested dict

Comment: In your dict, `print(a['RULES'])` gives `{ 'rule1': { 'Range': '0', 'Type': '0-10' }}`.Use `print(a['rule2'])` gives `{ 'Range': '1-10', 'Type': '0,10', }`.The structure is not the same.

Comment: As suggested by @jizhihaoSAMA that you don't have nested key `dict` inside each key that is the cause for error. **Note:** you can use `print` to debug and check before error line to see what's going on.

Comment: You have to handle nested dicts like ('RULE' and 'rule1'), if it is your real need. You can do it with a recursive call, if needed. See my answer below.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code as below:

```
dict1 = { 'RULES': { 'rule1': { 'Range': '0', 'Type': '0-10' }}, 'rule2': { 'Range': '1-10', 'Type': '0,10', }, 'rule3': { 'Range': '11-50', 'order': '3' } }


for i,j in dict1.items():

    for k,l in j.items():

        if 'dict' in str(type(l)):

            l['value'] = l['Type']
            if '-' in l['Type']:
                l['operator'] = '='
            if ',' in l['Type']:
                l['operator'] = 'in'


print(dict1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```py
d1 = {
    'RULES': {
        'rule1': { 'Range': '0', 'Type': '0-10' },
        'rule2': { 'Range': '1-10', 'Type': '0,10', },
        'rule3': { 'Range': '11-50', 'order': '3' }
    }
}

for v in d1.values():
    for y in v.values():
        if 'Type' in y.keys():
            y['value'] = y['Type']
            if '-' in y['Type']:
                y['operator'] = 'or'
            elif ',' in y['Type']:
                y['operator'] = '='
print(d1)
```

Output

```
{'RULES': {'rule1': {'Range': '0', 'Type': '0-10', 'value': '0-10', 'operator': 'or'}, 'rule2': {'Range': '1-10', 'Type': '0,10', 'value': '0,10', 'operator': '='}, 'rule3': {'Range': '11-50', 'order': '3'}}}
```

For easy to read,

```
d1 = {
    'RULES':{
        'rule1': {
            'Range': '0', 
            'Type': '0-10', 
            'value': '0-10', 
            'operator': 'or'
        },
        'rule2': {
            'Range': '1-10', 
            'Type': '0,10', 
            'value': '0,10', 
            'operator': '='
        },
        'rule3': {
            'Range': '11-50', 
            'order': '3'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For the sake of improving your coding skills, you might want to both use if statement rightfully, avoid multiple for statements (use recursive function instead). This will allow you to avoid corner cases causing issues.

Thus, you'll define a fonction to perform a recursive update of your dict object with the condition on the key 'Type' which must be available.

```
import re
def update_rule(rule: dict):
    if 'Type' in rule.keys():
        if ',' in rule['Type']:
            operator = '='
        else:
            operator = 'or'
        rule.update({'operator': operator})
    else:
        for v in rule.values():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                update_rule(v)
```

Then, to get you updated dictionary, just apply the function to your input:

```
update_rule(my_input_dict)
```

Answer (score -1):

With this code: you check if you have an inner dict with the 'Type' Key or not, like the "RULES" which contains "rule1", and you recursively call the function if it is the case.
Your error came from the fact you did not ckecked if an inner rule was present or not. You have to handle both cases in the code.

With this code you obtain the exact expected output:

```
dict1 = {
    'RULES': {
        'rule1': {
            'Range': '0',
            'Type': '0-10'
        }
    },
    'rule2': {
        'Range': '1-10',
        'Type': '0,10',
    },
    'rule3': {
        'Range': '11-50',
        'order': '3'
    }
}


def addValue(d):
    if type(d) == type({}):
        for i,j in d.items():
            ##print("(i, j)", i, j)
            if type({}) == type(j):
                if "Type" in j.keys():
                    j['value']=j['Type']
                    if '-' in j['Type']:
                        j['operator'] = 'or'
                    if ',' in j['Type']:
                        j['operator'] = '='

            addValue(j)

addValue(dict1)
print(dict1)
```

Output is:

```
{'RULES': {'rule1': {'Range': '0', 'Type': '0-10', 'value': '0-10', 'operator': 'or'}}, 'rule2': {'Range': '1-10', 'Type': '0,10', 'value': '0,10', 'operator': '='}, 'rule3': {'Range': '11-50', 'order': '3'}}
```

or for easy reading:

```
{'RULES':     {'rule1': {'Range': '0', 'Type': '0-10',
                         'value': '0-10', 'operator': 'or'}},

 'rule2': {'Range': '1-10', 'Type': '0,10',
             'value': '0,10', 'operator': '='},

 'rule3': {'Range': '11-50', 'order': '3'}
 }
```